# Function signature differences in C++11

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, g++, capture

Considering C++11's lambdas with the following code,

```
template <typename M>
void call(void (*f)(M), M m)
{
  f(m);
}

int main()
{
  call<int>([](int n) { }, 42);          // OK

  int r;
  call<int>([&](int n) { r = n; }, 42);  // KO
}
```

is there a signature difference between the lambdas that makes the second one incompatible with the argument of `call`?

I use g++ 4.6.1.

Side question: why can't the parameter be inferred if I write `call([](int n) { }, 42);`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only a captureless lambda can be implicitly converted to function pointer.

A lambda that captures variables cannot be converted to a function pointer because it has state that needs to be maintained (the captured variables) and that state cannot be represented by a function pointer.

The type `M` cannot be inferred from the function arguments because a conversion is required to convert the lambda to a function pointer.  That conversion inhibits template argument deduction.  If you were to call the function `call` with an actual function (e.g., `void f(int)`), argument deduction would work just fine.

Comment: Note that `M` is deduced by the second argument. So to make this work, we can make a non-deduced context in the first parameter. `void call(void (*f)(typename identity<M>::type), M m)`. Now, C++0x requires this work work. Some current compilers will require the whole parameter to be a non-deduced context (comeau doesn't, but GCC and clang afaik does). Hence to increase compatibility, one can say `void call(typename identity<void (*f)(M)>::type, M m)`. As it is a non-deduced context, it won't be compared, and cannot cause a deduction failure.

Comment: @Johannes:  Ah, slick.  I didn't know that a non-deduced context could be used to positively prohibit deduction; I thought it could only be used to negatively inhibit deduction.  Nice!

Answer (score 7):

As James already answered, only captureless lambdas can be converted to function pointers. Lambdas that have state create functor objects that implement `operator()`, and member function pointers are incompatible with free function pointers.

When the compiler processes: `[&](int n){ r = n; }` it generates something like:

```
class __annonymous_lambda_type {
   int & r;
public:
   __annonymous_lambda_type( int & r ) : r(r) {}
   void operator()( int n ) const {
      r = n; 
   }
} __lambda_instatiation;
```

The class is required to store the state of the lambda, in this case the reference to the external object that will be modified when the lambda is executed. That `void operator()(int)` cannot be bound to a `void (*)(int)`.

On the other hand, if the lambda is stateless, it can be implemented as a free function, like in the case `[]( int n ) { std::cout << "Hi" << n << std::endl ; }`

```
void __annonymous_lambda_function( int n ) {
   std::cout << "Hi " << n << std::endl;
}
```

Because the lambda does not need to keep any state at all, and as such it can be kept as a plain function.